# `require': cannot load such file -- net/ssh (LoadError)

Tags: ruby

run a ruby script got error `require': cannot load such file -- net/ssh (LoadError)

```
bash-3.2$ rvm --default ruby-2.0.0-p451

-bash-3.2$ rvm list  

rvm rubies

=* ruby-2.0.0-p451 [ x86_64 ]

-bash-3.2$ gem list --local        

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.2.0)
bundler (1.5.3)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
executable-hooks (1.3.1)
gem-wrappers (1.2.4)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.7.7)
minitest (4.3.2)
net-ssh (2.9.1)
psych (2.0.0)
rake (0.9.6)
rdoc (4.0.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.2)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
test-unit (2.0.0.0)
```

ruby test.rb
`require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)

```
$ cat test.rb

require 'rubygems'
require 'net/ssh'

Net::SSH.start(...)
```

what's wrong? please advice. thanks

Comment: 1) check the current ruby version by running `ruby -v` 2) try to run same code in `irb` interactive shell

Comment: @zed_0xff,1)ruby-2.0.0-p451 2) it worked in irb

Comment: ...and try to print constant `RUBY_VERSION` from inside `irb`, maybe `irb` actually uses a different ruby interpreter? Also you can check a `~/.irbrc` file for some irb-specific initializers